# Manually bounce UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, bounce, uiattachmentbehavior

With UIScrollView, it's possible to programmatically move to an offset, with `setContentOffset:animated:` for exemple.

I'm trying to add a bounce effect when the offset is set programmatically. I think I should use a UIAttachmentBehavior, but I don't really know how to use it.

When should it be declared ? When the user finish dragging, in the `scrollViewDidEndDragging` function ? Or when the offset is the same than the final offset ?

For exemple, I'm at `offset 10` and I want to go to `offset 50`. Maybe I should go to `offset 60` and set a UIAttachmentBehavior at `offset 50` ? Or maybe there's an other way ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want to enable bouncing when you get to the edge of a scroll view.

If you want the default of the scrollview to be that it doesn't bounce, then use this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.scrollview.bounces = false
}
```

Then, if you want to enable bouncing at any point, just add the line:

```
self.scrollview.bounces = true
```

If you know that you always want to scrollview to bounce you can set the following properties:

```
self.scrollview.alwaysBounceVertical = true
self.scrollview.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
```

See [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollview_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/bounces) for more information.